# Record source and control source in ms access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a continuous form in MS Access 2010. In the details section of the form, I have two text boxes (named txtProj and txtArtifact).

There are 2 tables in the database. 
tblProject and tblArtifact.

```
tblProject has [Project ID] - autonumber and [Project Name] - string.
tblArtifact has [Artifact ID] - autonumber, [Project] - number and [Artifact Name] - string.
```

`[Project ID]` and `[Project]` are related by one-to-many relationship.

The Record Source for the form is tblArtifact. Now, in the textbox named txtProject, I want to display name of the project, rather than Project ID.

I am not able to figure out, how to refer to a control source of a table, which is not record source of the form.

Please help me.

I would be happy to provide any additional details, if required.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by joining the two tables,

```
SELECT  b.[Artifact Name]
FROM    tblProject a
        INNER JOIN tblArtifact b
            ON a.[ProjectID] = b.[Project]
WHERE   b.Project = 'value'
```

Comment: HI John.. where to enter this?? Shall I enter above code in control source property of txtProject??

Comment: Also, what are a and b in above query??

Comment: @Jay `a` abd `b` are called `alias`. it may keep the code shorter than typing the whole table name.

Comment: but shall they be entered in control source property of txtProject??

Comment: @Jay follow-up question, how do you retrieve data from the database?

Comment: Data is retrieved from database by use of Queries. So, am i supposed to populate txtProject field by using a VBA query??

Answer (score 0):

All that was required to be done was this:

1. Set record source property of the form as:

```
SELECT
    tblProject.*,
    tblArtifact.*
FROM tblProject INNER JOIN tblArtifact ON
    tblProject.[Project ID] = tblArtifact.Project;
```

2. Now the control source property gets additional drop down options where `[Project Name]` is included. Select that.